# JSX element type 'ReSlide' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**I import component  as:**

```
import {Slide as ReSlide} from 'react-awesome-reveal';
```

**the code as :**

```
       <ReSlide direction="up"  delay={-100}>         
            </ReSlide>
```

and on js working fine but i use it on tsx they give me error :
"JSX element type 'ReSlide' does not have any construct or call signatures."
how to solve it i have to make build of project!

Comment: i used it with typescript as you mentioned but it didn't give any errors. are you using the latest version of the package?

Comment: yes i used the last version yesterday i was install it

Comment: i think we need more details on what you trying to achieve. if you are using this just to show some text it should be fine.

Comment: i just use it to show element on my slider

Answer (score 0):

Try this ccreate a file named react-awesome-reveal.d.ts (you can name it differently if you prefer) at the same level as your other TypeScript files.

Inside this file, define the type for the Slide component from the react-awesome-reveal module:

```
    declare module 'react-awesome-reveal' {
      import * as React from 'react';
    
      export interface SlideProps {
        direction?: string;
        delay?: number;
        children: React.ReactNode;
      }
    
      export const Slide: React.FC<SlideProps>;
    }
```

This declaration file tells TypeScript how to interpret the Slide component from the react-awesome-reveal module and what props it accepts.

Now, in your TypeScript file (.tsx), you can import and use the ReSlide component without any errors:

```
    <ReSlide direction="up" delay={-100}>
          {/* Your content */}
        </ReSlide>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the package again and it worked fine,
I think the difference was on the package